# Accessing non-related entities in LinqToSql entity classes

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity, datacontext

In LinqToSql, if I want to access a non-related entity in an entity partial class, how do I do this without creating a new `DataContext`?

Here's the scenario:

I have the tables `Client`, `IssueType` and `ClientIssueType`. A `Client` may specify a list of `IssueTypes` if they do not want to use the default `IssueTypes`. I have the default `IssueTypes` in the `ClientIssueType` table with a `ClientId` of `null`.

In my `Client` partial I'd like to try to retrieve all `IssueTypes`, and if none are found, return all default `IssueTypes`. The only way I can see of accessing the `IssueTypes` with a `null ClientId` is by accessing the table through a new `DataContext`, which is problematic once I want to start assigning them to `Issues`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by moving the logic out of the entity partial class and into the DataContext partial class. When I call the method I pass in the `Client` entity.